# is it possible to get element from tuple of named tuples by key?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, namedtuple

I defined this named tuple

```
_validation_message = namedtuple("_validation_message", "validation msg")
```

and use it as a value inside a regular tuple like this:

```
_messages = (
        _validation_message("mandatory", "mandatory field"),
        _validation_message("phone", "please enter a valid phone number"),
        _validation_message("name", "please enter both first and last name separated by space")
)
```

Now, I am trying to get a specific _validation_message from _messages by validation name, for example, I want that _messages["mandatory"] will return "mandatory field".
is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Use a dictionary instead?

Comment: if there is no other simple option to achive that with named tuple i will use dictionary

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the below structure:

```
_validation_type = namedtuple("_validation_type", "mandatory phone name")

_messages = _validation_type(
    mandatory="mandatory field",
    phone="please enter a valid phone number",
    name="please enter both first and last name separated by space"
)
```

and access it by:

```
_messages.mandatory
```

Answer (score 0):

> _messages["mandatory"] will return "mandatory field"

To achieve this, you must first realise that `messages` is a tuple, so you  will have to access the `_validation_message` objects present in it, and then filter out the ones you need.

Furthermore, you've stated you want to get the `msg` attribute of the `_validation_message` object, for which `validation` is equal to `'mandatory'`.

This can be done by iterating over the tuple while checking for your condition:

```
>>> for vm in _messages:
...     if vm.validation == 'mandatory':
...         print(vm.msg)
...
mandatory field
```

Comment: I dont want to iterate over all items every time i want a specific one, but thanks.